# Look at the question and see me

Tags: riddle

Some can be forgiven for thinking I watch you, 
but in fact you are the one watching me.
I suppose I keep an eye on the mathy fellow,
but that just makes me a little bit gooey.

I guess I don't lead but I can be led,
though sometimes I have crystallizing moments.
without light I am out of sight however, 
with a magnet I can get real funky.

To give your answer you would key,
but you would get little feedback without me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> A (computer) monitor

Some can be forgiven for thinking I watch you,
but in fact you are the one watching me.

> A monitor can be one who watches, but in this case, I'm looking at my monitor right now

I suppose I keep an eye on the mathy fellow,
but that just makes me a little bit gooey.

> Not entirely, sure, but I'm guessing the mathy fellow is the CPU?

I guess I don't lead but I can be led,

> LED monitors

though sometimes I have crystallizing moments.

> Or liquid crystal monitors

without light I am out of sight however,

> You can't see anything if the monitor produces no light

with a magnet I can get real funky.

> Especially if you're a CRT monitor, as magnets will distort the picture

To give your answer you would key, but you would get little feedback without me.

> I won't know I'm right until I see a response to this on my monitor :)

Comment: You answered too fast for me :) I watch you = video chat? Gooey = GUI?

Comment: @Somo145 Lucky timing. :) GUI sounds very plausible.

Comment: the I watch you part is from the term monitor being something that watches over something. but yeah I made this one a little easy, with riddles it is rather difficult too balance too broad and too easy.

Comment: And yes the mathy fellow do be the cpu

Comment: I like simpler riddles like this. it makes me feel smarter :)